Can't ping sites over IPv6. Sometimes works, sometimes never get a response
I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and I'm facing a strange issue with IPv6. Sometimes, I cannot ping IPv6 websites, like ipv6.google.com or even google.com using their IPv6 address. This issue causes browsers to load websites indefinitely.
The strangest part is that my PC is dual-booted with Windows 11, and on Windows, the ping works perfectly. Additionally, other Linux distributions (non-Debian-based), like Manjaro, work fine too (tested using a live USB).
Here’s some information that might help identify the issue.
Settings in my Router
The connection to my ISP (WAN) is made via PPPoE using IPv4. They do not support establishing PPPoE over IPv6.

Getting IPv6 from the ISP using SLAAC;
Using prefix delegation (/64);
DNS address is provided by the ISP for now.

With this configuration, I successfully get a public IPv6 address from the ISP.
The LAN configuration for delivering IPv6 is SLAAC + Stateless DHCP.
If I ping ipv6.google.com directly from the router interface:
PING ipv6.google.com (2800:3f0:4002:810::200e): 64 data bytes

Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=1 time=39.723 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=2 time=39.825 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=3 time=44.562 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=4 time=39.262 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=5 time=40.207 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=6 time=40.878 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=7 time=39.551 ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4002:810::200e: bytes=64 ttl=58 seq=8 time=39.319 ms

--- Ping Statistic "ipv6.google.com" ---

Packets: Sent=8, Received=8, Lost=0 (0.00% loss)

Round-trip min/avg/max = 39.262/40.416/44.562 ms

ping is stopped.

As you can see, it worked perfectly!
My PC
Now, here’s the configuration where I think the problem lies. I’m using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with NextDNS configured in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.
The output of ip addr is:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:17:72:7a:97:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 70:85:c2:24:6a:87
    inet 192.168.10.61/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 84955sec preferred_lft 84955sec
    inet6 2804:7f0:a210:e963:9466:90d6:6d6e:7294/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 295sec preferred_lft 295sec
    inet6 fe80::9fd2:1acf:9bcc:c800/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp114s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:f6:da:66:12:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Alright, now let's take a look at the problem itself.
johndoe@ubuntu:~$ ping ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com (2800:3f0:4002:810::200e) 56 data bytes
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
49 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 49134ms

All packets lost. Now let`s see with IPv4:
johndoe@ubuntu:~$ ping -4 google.com
PING google.com (142.251.133.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=39.1 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=41.2 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=44.8 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=42.1 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=42.2 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=6 ttl=116 time=42.9 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=7 ttl=116 time=39.0 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=8 ttl=116 time=43.0 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=9 ttl=116 time=40.1 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=10 ttl=116 time=41.5 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=11 ttl=116 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from eze10s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.133.238): icmp_seq=12 ttl=116 time=41.4 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 12 received, 0% packet loss, time 11014ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.373/41.303/44.832/1.811 ms

IPv4 worked fine.
We can also check the traceroute for ipv6.google.com:
johndoe@ubuntu:~$ traceroute ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2800:3f0:4002:810::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

Some additional infos
My DNS configuration
john@dow:~$ resolvectl 
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: uplink
Current DNS Server: 2a07:a8c1::#78da41.dns.nextdns.io
       DNS Servers: 45.90.28.0#78da41.dns.nextdns.io 2a07:a8c0::#78da41.dns.nextdns.io 45.90.30.0#78da41.dns.nextdns.io
                    2a07:a8c1::#78da41.dns.nextdns.io

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp114s0f0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Pinging IPv6 using Windows
PowerShell 7.4.6
PS C:\Users\johndoe> ping ipv6.google.com

Pinging ipv6.l.google.com [2800:3f0:4001:806::200e] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2800:3f0:4001:806::200e: time=13ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4001:806::200e: time=9ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4001:806::200e: time=10ms
Reply from 2800:3f0:4001:806::200e: time=8ms

Ping statistics for 2800:3f0:4001:806::200e:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 8ms, Maximum = 13ms, Average = 10ms
PS C:\Users\johndoe>

Traceroute using Windows
PS C:\Users\johndoe> tracert ipv6.google.com

Tracing route to ipv6.l.google.com [2800:3f0:4001:806::200e]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  2804:7f0:a212:ca48:c5c0:e6e1:39d6:5048
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     7 ms     6 ms     6 ms  2001:12e0:500:0:1::289d
  4     4 ms     4 ms    12 ms  2001:12e0:100:2008:a002:2009:a005:2
  5     9 ms     4 ms     6 ms  2001:12e0:100:2008:a002:1030:a002:3
  6     *        *       10 ms  2001:12e0:100:1017:a001:1030:a002:36
  7     9 ms     *        *     2001:4860:1:1::d84
  8    12 ms    11 ms    12 ms  2800:3f0:8362:c0::1
  9     7 ms     5 ms     5 ms  2001:4860:0:1::24f6
 10    10 ms    12 ms     5 ms  2001:4860:0:1::7cac
 11    11 ms    15 ms     8 ms  2001:4860:0:1::7cc7
 12     5 ms     5 ms    12 ms  2001:4860:0:1::8ff9
 13    11 ms    10 ms    12 ms  2800:3f0:4001:806::200e

Trace complete.

Edit 1:
Results of ip -6 neigh
fe80::66:ffff:feac:6d91 dev enp0s31f6 lladdr 10:fe:ed:ff:fa:ce router REACHABLE 
fe80::b219:21ff:fef7:8f8c dev enp0s31f6 lladdr b0:19:21:f7:8f:8c router REACHABLE

Results of ip -6 route
2804:7f0:a210:ec6d::/64 dev enp0s31f6 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default proto ra metric 100 pref medium
    nexthop via fe80::b219:21ff:fef7:8f8c dev enp0s31f6 weight 1 
    nexthop via fe80::66:ffff:feac:6d91 dev enp0s31f6 weight 1 

Results of sudo ip6tables -L -v -n
sudo ip6tables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 


Check your routing tables, probably the default is not pointing to the gateway you would expect. SLAAC provides an IP address, but you still need need the gateway to be advertised. Check ip -6 neigh and ip -6 route and the firewall ip6tables -L -v -n

Thanks for your comment @sleepyhead. Iǜe added the result of your suggestions. I don't know how to interpret those results and if those are normal or not, but the result are in the end of the question, in "Edit 1".

So you have 2 default routes with nexthop to prefix starting fe80, those are link local. I would have expected something in the provider range 2804:7f0:a210:ec6d::/64. link local gateway could work, also the two gateways is not impossible, but if it doesn't work, it's because the routes are not correct

The first default route, I believe, is from my router because it shares the end of the IP address. My router's IP is 2804:7F0:A210:F1AE:B219:21FF:FEF7:8F8C/64. As for the second default route, I have no idea where it comes from. In any case, this explains why the ping sometimes works and sometimes does not.

Finally found the problem. I had another router in my network with IPv4 DHCP disabled. I was using this router as a access point, however, I cannot disable the IPv6 DHCP. I had to turn it off. When I did that, the second default gateway was gone.

I found the problem. I had a second router in my network that was advertising an IPv6 address. This second router was supposed to function as an access point, not as a DHCP server. However, I couldn't find an option in the settings to disable the router's DHCPv6 (only for IPv4).
I ended up turning the router off. When I did that, the second default gateway disappeared, and the issue with pinging IPv6 sites was resolved.
Results of ip -6 route:
2804:7f0:a210:f616::/64 dev enp0s31f6 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::b219:21ff:fef7:8f8c dev enp0s31f6 proto ra metric 100 pref medium

Results of ping: ping -6 google.com:
PING google.com (2800:3f0:4002:801::200e) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4002:801::200e: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=38.7 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4002:801::200e: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=40.6 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4002:801::200e: icmp_seq=3 ttl=113 time=38.7 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4002:801::200e: icmp_seq=4 ttl=113 time=40.9 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4002:801::200e: icmp_seq=5 ttl=113 time=42.6 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4002:801::200e: icmp_seq=6 ttl=113 time=38.4 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.393/39.961/42.558/1.517 ms

